# Is "available for the world" OK?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've just put a new web page live, and now one of my sentences is bugging me. The sentence in question is:

> It was developed internally and made available for the world.

The part that I'm not sure about is **made available for the world**. Is *for* correct here, or would the appropriate word be *to*?

It sounds right to me, but I'm not sure if I'm breaking a rule.

Comment: Your sentence is fine as it is, but so is the alternative.  Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Anonym [Hardly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+available+to+the+world%2Cmade+available+for+the+world&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20available%20to%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20available%20for%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

The question was:

> Is “available for the world” OK?

To which the simplest and most direct answer is “Why no, no it isn’t.”  (But do see Exceptions below.) There’s simply no contest here: you have to use *to*. It turns out that [*made available **to** the world*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22made%20available%20to%20the%20world%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) beats out [*made available **for** the world*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22made%20available%20for%20the%20world%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) by ***at least* two orders of magnitude** in [this Google N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+available+to+the+world%2Cmade+available+for+the+world&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20available%20to%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20available%20for%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

### Exceptions

If you dig down, you’ll discover that in actual practice, the **only** time that you would **ever** use *made available **for** the world* is when it is followed by a phrase in which *world* plays some other important rôle, and so is not itself the object of a preposition.

Two situations come to mind.

The first is with *world* serving as the subject of an infinitive clause in the verb phrase following:

> This work has been made available **for the world at large to collectively appreciate and enjoy.**

The second is when *world* gets used for a possessive *world’s*, and therefore is not the head of the noun phrase following:

> This work has been made available **for the world’s collective appreciation and enjoyment.**

So you would not **end** a sentence with *made available **for** the world*; you would have to have more to the phrase.

Comment: Wow, OK. Is this a hard and fast rule? The more I think about it the more it makes sense.

Comment: @anthony-arnold We don’t really have much in the way of hard-and-fast “rules” in English, just usage patterns.  But see my update for those extremely rare occasions when *for* is better: there must be more to the phrase.